# keeping x:Class property at the top of the xaml window Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xaml

Is there a way to keep the x:Class property in my xaml to stay at the top? It keeps changing to the middle

[image]

Is there a way that it can stay at the top of the window by default? like this

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing that makes it move? I've never seen it do that

Comment: You're using some kind of plugin that's rearranging your xaml. Don't use it.

Comment: whenever i add a new thing into xaml that didn't have a reference before so lets say i add a thing into xaml that didn't have a definition and it adds a new xmlns

Comment: do you think resharper could be the problem?

Comment: i just tried it without resharper and still have the same problem

Comment: I've never seen this behavior, either with or without ReSharper